# nested form in activeadmin empties values on submit before validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a has_many relationship between `Trials` and `TrialSlots`. This is the `app/models/trial.rb`:

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :start_date, :trial_duration, :subjects_count, presence: true
  has_many :trial_slots
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_slots
end
```

I want to be able to add and edit TrialSlots from the edit form of a Trial, hence I added this to `app/admin/trial.rb`

```
  form do |f|
    # […] some basic inputs skipped for brevity

    f.has_many :trial_slots do |trial_slot|
      f.inputs "Slots" do
        trial_slot.input :start_time, as: :time_picker
        trial_slot.input :end_time, as: :time_picker
      end

    end

    f.actions
  end
```

Since I'm using Rails4 I already had to add:

```
  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(trial: [ :start_date, :trial_duration, :title,
                    :break_duration, :subjects_count, :reward, :location,
                    :agency_name, :agency_address, :contact_name,
                    :contact_email, :contact_phone, trial_slots_attributes: [:start_date, :end_date] ],
                   )
    end
  end
```

The direct attributes of a Trial are saved as expected. But the attributes of the trial slots are somehow emptied before validation (:start_date and :end_date are both required, thus failing to save). Why?

**UPDATE:**

I worked around the problem by allowing every parameters.

```
  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit!
    end
  end
```

In this specific case, this is reasonable since it's all inside of `/admin`. However I still wonder how to get this working without the workaround.

Comment: Are you sure the trial_slot_attributes are being send correctly? What is the output of params.inspect, before it is filtered by strong_paramers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has `start_time` and `end_time`, while your params permit `start_date` and `end_date`. If the code you posted above is correct, that'll likely be your problem.